# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException does not get called

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that has the following code in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure that any exceptions that we don't handle at least get logged.
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += LogUnhandledException;
}

private void LogUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Log.Error.LogException("UnhandledException", e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
}
```

The idea is to at least log all exceptions that are unhanded.

But it does not seem to ever be called.  I tried doing a Divide by Zero in one of my service operations and it just stops the service after it hits the exception.

```
int zero = 0;
int result = 100 / zero;
```

The LogUnhandledException method never gets called.

I have tried this in both IIS and running in the debugger.

**How can I get this event to work for a WCF service?**

Comment: I wonder if it's something to do with IIS or the way WCF service is hosted. Like [here](http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/catching-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net/), the guys says: *In summary, unhandled exceptions in an ASP.NET application can be caught with an Application_Error event handler in the global.asax, or by creating a HttpModule to catch the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [unhandled exception filter for an app domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) is a last-ditch attempt to allow the application to log meaningful information before it is terminated.

> This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the application to log information about the exception before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and **terminates the application**.

If WCF allowed an exception thrown by a service to be completely unhandled in this way it would mean that when the service is hosted in IIS the entire worker process would be terminated because a single request raised an exception - not a desirable outcome.  As a result WCF doesn't leave exceptions thrown by services unhandled - *this event will not be raised in this case*.

If you want to log exceptions thrown by WCF services then take a look at the [`IErrorHandler` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751439.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try also catching a ThreadException, e.g.

```
        Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

I had the same issue in the WinForms app a while ago. *UnhandledException* is raised for truly unhandled exceptions that would normally terminate your entire process immediately. Typically there's a global handler that doesn't let that happen, and provides some default behavior. So you need to catch the exception before it goes to that handler. This can be done via a ThreadException.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(LogUnhandledException);
```

I'm wondering what is difference between your call and this one, with the "+= new"... but it's worth the try.

Comment: There is no difference.  One is just "old school" C# notation.  They compile the same.